# Storing html elements created by Jquery in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add two div elements to my html body, I start by creating the div elements assigning a unique id and storing them in two variables.

```
var a = $('div').attr('id', 'container');         
var b= $('div').attr('id', 'selectable');     

 $(a).appendTo('body');
 $(b).appendTo('body);
```

The problem is when I add them to the body, I notice only one div element is actually being appended to the body. Upon further inspection, I noticed that the content in variable b is being copied to variable a, so variable a and b both refer to the same div with ID selectable.

How do I create two unique div elements to be appended to the html body?

Comment: `$('<div />', {id:'container'})`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are selecting divs, not creating them.

```
var a = $('div').attr('id', 'container');
var b = $('div').attr('id', 'selectable');
```

Should be:

```
var a = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'container');
var b = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'selectable');
```

Comment: or something like $("body").append("<div>lol i am div a</div>")

Answer (score 4):

This searches the dom for all div elements:

```
$('div');
```

So the following code is applying the id of 'selectable' to all div elements.

```
var a = $('div').attr('id', 'container');         
var b = $('div').attr('id', 'selectable');
```

To create an element in jQuery, you need to have a string that begins with '<'.  To get the result you want, you probably want to do the following:

```
var a = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'container');
a.appendTo('body');
```

You could also do:

```
var a = $('<div id="container" />').appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick hack?

This code **SELECTS** matching elements from the DOM

`var a = $('div').attr('id', 'container');`

To store a certain div in a variable, use jQuery's `.clone();` method.

So for example

`var div_copy = $('div').clone(); //Saved for later use`